# CSS - intersection of img and text element with negative margin cause strange behavior

Tags: css, margin

I trying to put text with a color background over an image using a negative margin. But it causes a strange behavior. The text is displayed over the image, but the text's background shows up under the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/jcjb5v7q/

Html:

```
<img src="http://freedogpics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pictures_1407299643.jpg"
     height="100" />
<p>TEST</p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:2em;
    background:yellow;
}
```

[image]

I know that I can use `background-image` or absolute position. `Background-image` is good for one image, in real project I have several images with parallel. I don't want use absolute position, because it is breaks down the flow of document.

Comment: Just reset the positioning context by using position relative on the patagraph - http://jsfiddle.net/jcjb5v7q/2/

Comment: The two elements basically, as I understand it, have the same z-index (in the absence of any positioning context) so the browser renders background first then the actual elements...it's a browser thing! To combat this you have to establish a stacking/rendering order using z-index which requires a positioning context.

Comment: you can use `position:relative` http://jsfiddle.net/jcjb5v7q/4/